# How can I find out how many lines are between a number and the next occurrence of the same number in a file?

Tags: bash, awk, vim

I have large files that each store results from very long calculations.  Here's an example of a file where there are results for five time steps; there are problems with the output at the **third, fourth, and fifth** time steps.

(Please note that I have been lazy and have used the same numbers to represent the results at each time step in my example.  In reality, the numbers would be unique at each time step.)

```
     3
 i =        1, time =        1.000, E =     1234567
  Mg       22.9985897185        6.9311166109        0.7603733573
  O        23.0438129644        6.4358253659        1.5992513709
  O        23.8223149199        7.2029442290        0.4030956770
     3
 i =        2, time =        1.500, E =     1234567
  Mg       22.9985897185        6.9311166109        0.7603733573
  O        23.0438129644        6.4358253659        1.5992513709
  O        23.8223149199        7.2029442290        0.4030956770
     3
 i =        3, time =        2.000, E =     1234567
  Mg       22.9985897185        6.9311166109        0.7603733573
  O        23.0438129644        6.4358253659        1.5992513709
  O        23.8223149199                                       (<--Problem: calculation stopped and some numbers are missing)
     3
 i =        4, time =        2.500, E =     1234567
  Mg       22.9985897185        6.9311166109        0.7603733573
  O        23.0438129644        6.4358253659        1.5992513709 (Problem: calculation stopped and entire row is missing below)
     3
 i =        5, time =        3.000, E =     1234567
  Mg       22.9985897185        6.9311166109        0.7603733573
  O        23.0438129644        6.4358253659        1.5992513709
  O        23.8223149199        7.2029442290        0.4030956770 sdffs (<--Problem: rarely, additional characters can be printed but I figured out how to identify the longest lines in the file and don't have this problem this time)
```

The problem is that the calculations can fail (and then need to be restarted) as a result is printing to a file.  That means that when I try to use the results, I have problems.

My question is, **how can I find out when something has gone wrong and the results file has been messed up**? The most common problem is that there are not "3" lines of results (plus the header, which is the line where there's i = ...)?  If I could find a problem line, I could then delete that time step.

Here is an example of error output I get when trying to use a messed-up file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mtn/storage/software/languages/anaconda/Anaconda3-2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aser/io/extxyz.py", line 593, in read_xyz
    nentss = int(line)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonPostProcessingCode.py", line 25, in <module>
    path = read('%s%s' % (filename, fileext) , format='xyz', index=':')  # <--This line tells me that Python cannot read in a particular time step because the formatting is messed up.
```

I am not experienced with scripting/Awk, etc, so if anyone thinks I have not used appropriate question tags, a heads-up would be welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you can come up with a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output that just demonstrates your problem. For example imagine each block should have, say, 3 lines instead of 330 lines - show some sample input where you have, say, 3 blocks where the first 2 have 3 lines but the 3rd only has 2 lines. Now add the expected output for that. That would be a [mcve] that we could use to not only better understand your problem but also test a potential solution against. Then you just change `3` to `330` in the code to run it on your real data

Comment: It should be extremely easy - just take what you have, throw away all but the `i =` lines and 2 lines below each plus the `330` lines above them if they really are present in your input. Now add a 3rd block that has 1 less line than those.

Comment: I added a [mcve] to my answer based on what I think you're requirements are.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you and sorry it took me so long (the reality is complicated so it took a while to boil it down; hope it's helpful).  I will take a look at what you have done.  Thanks very much.

Comment: No problem. You showed us `an example of error output I get when trying to use a messed-up file` but we don't care about that as it's unrelated to the problem you're asking for help with which is how to discard these erroneous records before the next tool runs on them and produces that output. What you need to add instead is the output you expect from the tool you're asking us to help you write given the input you provided.

Comment: @EdMorton, apologies. Hmm, I will think about how to demonstrate that.  The desired output is a file that combines two results files--the one that's messed up and another one. I don't think it would be useful for you to see it because things would quickly get confusing (at least, I doubt I could do a good job of avoiding confusing people).  Is it sufficient to say that the immediate problem is that there's a formatting error in the problem file that's preventing it from being processed? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Again, don;t worry about what your final output from your complete toolset is here, just what you want the output of **this** specific tool you're asking for help to write should be. Is it the list of valid records, the list of invalid records, the valid in one output file with the invalid in the other, a list of all records decorated with "valid" and "invalid" at the start or something else. You can take whatever you get from this question and modify it later to do whatever else you want.

Comment: @EdMorton, in that case, what I want here is for the Python "read" method to work--for the problem file to be read in with the read-in failing because of formatting problems.

Comment: There isn't a hint about "Python" in your question so far. You tagged your question with awk, and mentioned awk in the text and so you're getting awk answers. If you wanted a python solution then that was a bad idea as it's wasted of everyones time trying to help you and hasn't attracted people who are interested in and understand python to your question. I personally don't have the faintest idea what it'd take for the python "read method" to work or how to solve your problem in python.

Comment: @EdMorton, Awk is the most efficient way, in my experience to find formatting problems with the files I'm dealing with.  The only reason Python matters is that it's the tool I'm using to perform a processing task.  The processing task fails because of formatting issues that can be identified by Awk.  I am now going to focus on working with the answers other people have kindly provided.

Comment: OK then forget about python again as that's apparently irrelevant. Does [the answer I provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67805187/1745001) not do exactly what you need? You must have some specific output in mind given the sample input you provided for the tool you're asking for help to write, whether that output will be input to some python tool or some other tool - just add that expected output to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header plus 330 mean 331 lines of text and so

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="i =" } { split($0,bits,"\n");if (length(bits)-1==331) { print RS$0 } }' file > newfile
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
             RS="i =" 
           } 
           { 
             split($0,bits,"\n");
             if (length(bits)-1==331) { 
                print RS$0 
             } 
           }' file > newfile
```

Before processing any lines from the file called file, set the record separator equal to "i =". Then, for each record, use, split to split the record ($0) into an array bits based on a new line as the separator. Where the length of the array bits, less 1 is 331 print the record separator plus the record, redirecting the output to a new file called newfile

Comment: You should mention you need GNU awk for multi-char RS. With a POSIX awk `RS="i ="` will be treated as if you wrote `RS="i"`.

Comment: @Raman Sailopal, thank you.  I tried this and it's giving me a "newfile" but it contains only one time step that does have 330 lines (plus the header).  Trying to figure out why.

Comment: @Ant what is the output of `awk --version`?

Comment: @Ed Morton, it's "GNU Awk 4.0.2."

Comment: OK, good, then that rules out multi-char RS as being the problem. See my comment under your question for how we can best help you.

Comment: @RamanSailopal, thanks, I found that your solution works best with my files, which are huge.

Comment: This prints an additional empty line after each record. I think you should replace `print RS$0` with `printf "%s",RS$0`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^ i =/  {
    prt()
    expNumLines = prev + 1
    actNumLines = 2
    rec = prev RS $0
    next
}
NF == 4 {
    rec = rec RS $0
    actNumLines++
}
{ prev = $0 }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( (actNumLines == expNumLines) && (rec != "") ) {
        print "-------------"
        print rec
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
-------------
     3
 i =        3, time =        2.000, E =     1234567
  Mg       22.9985897185        6.9311166109        0.7603733573
  O        23.0438129644        6.4358253659        1.5992513709
-------------
     3
 i =        5, time =        3.000, E =     1234567
  Mg       22.9985897185        6.9311166109        0.7603733573
  O        23.0438129644        6.4358253659        1.5992513709
```

Just change the `prt()` function to do whatever it is you want to do with valid records.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not really bash-related, but may be of interest if performance is an issue, since you seem to handle very large files.

Considering that you can compile some very basic C programs, you may build this code:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Constants are hardcoded to make the program more readable
// But they could be passed as program argument
const char separator[]="i =";
const unsigned int requiredlines=331;

int main(void) {
    char* buffer[331] = { NULL, };
    ssize_t buffersizes[331] = { 0, };
    size_t n = requiredlines+1; // Ignore lines until the separator is found
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t nbread;
    size_t i;

    // Iterate through all lines
    while ((nbread = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {

        // If the separator is found:
        // - print the record (if valid)
        // - reset the record (always)
        if (strstr(line, separator)) {
            if (n == requiredlines) {
                for (i = 0 ; i < requiredlines ; ++i) printf("%s", buffer[i]);
            }
            n = 0;
        }

        // Add the line to the buffer, unless too many lines have been read
        // (in which case we may discard lines until the separator is found again)
        if (n < requiredlines) {
            if (buffersizes[n] > nbread) {
                strncpy(buffer[n], line, nbread);
                buffer[n][nbread] = '\0';
            } else {
                free(buffer[n]);
                buffer[n] = line;
                buffersizes[n] = nbread+1;
                line = NULL;
                len = 0;
            }
        }
        ++n;
    }

    // Don't forget about the last record, if valid
    if (n == requiredlines) {
        for (i = 0 ; i < requiredlines ; ++i) printf("%s", buffer[i]);
    }

    free(line);
    for (i = 0 ; i < requiredlines ; ++i) free(buffer[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The program can be compiled like this:

```sh
gcc -c prog.c && gcc -o prog prog.o
```

Then it may be executed like this:

```sh
./prog < infile > outfile
```

To simplify the code, it reads from stdin and outputs to stdout, but that’s more than enough in Bash considering all the options at your disposal to redirect streams. If need be, the code can be adapted to read/write directly from/to files.

I have tested it on a generated file with 10 million lines and compared it to the awk-based solution.

```
(time awk 'BEGIN { RS="i =" } { split($0,bits,"\n");if (length(bits)-1==331) { printf "%s",RS$0 } }' infile) > outfile

real    0m24.655s
user    0m24.357s
sys     0m0.279s

(time ./prog < infile) > outfile

real    0m1.414s
user    0m1.291s
sys     0m0.121s
```

With this example it runs approximately 18 times faster than the awk solution. Your mileage may vary (different data, different hardware) but I guess it should always be significantly faster.

I should mention that the awk solution is impressively fast (for a scripted solution, that is). I have first tried to code the solution in C++ and it had similar performance as awk, and sometimes it was even slower than awk.

Comment: I really appreciate it, thank you.  There are a number of things unrelated to this question that it will be very useful for. indeed  I wish I could give you more credit for your efforts than an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit more difficult to spread the match of a record across 2 lines to try and incorporate the `i = ...`, but I don't think you actually need to.  It looks like a new record can be distinguished by the occurrence of a line with only one column.  If that is the case, you could do something like:

```
awk -v c=330 -v p=1 'function pr(n) {
    if( n - p == c)  printf "%s", buf; 
    buf = ""} 
    NF == 1 { pr(NR); p = NR; c = $1 } 
    {buf = sprintf("%s%s\n", buf, $0)} 
    END {pr(NR+1)}' input-file
```

In the above, whenever a line is seen with a single record, the expectation is that many lines will be in the following record.  If that number is not matched, the record is not printed.  To avoid that logic, just remove the `c = $1` near the end of line 4.  The only reason you need the `-v c=330` is to enable the removal of that assignment; if you want the single column line to be the line count of the record, you can omit `-v c=330`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csplit` to grab each record in separate files, if you are allowed to write intermediate files.

```sh
csplit -k infile '/i = /' {*}
```

Then you can see which records are complete and which ones are not using `wc -l xx*` (note: `xx` is the default prefix of split files).

Then you can do whatever you want with those records, including listing files that have exactly 331 lines:

```sh
wc -l xx* | sed -n 's/^ *331 \(xx.*\)/\1/p'
```

Should you want to build a new file with all *valid* records, simply concatenate them:

```sh
wc -l xx* | sed -n 's/^ *331 \(xx.*\)/\1/p' | xargs cat > newfile
```

You can also, among other uses, archive failed records:

```sh
wc -l xx* | sed -e '$d' -e '/^ *331 \(xx.*\)/d' | xargs cat > failures
```

Comment: thank you; this would probably work for shorter simulations (mine have taken months and the files are huge).  I tried it and found that my current files are so large that things keep freezing.

Comment: I cannot advocate for the efficiency of `csplit` on very large files. Thank you for trying. If you need to do this operation pretty often with huge files, I would recommend programming in C/C++ which should offer the best performance.